# How to get two columns result with Union all

Tags: mysql, union-all

I need Get (Debe and Haber) Columns on Result, i am using Union All but i get always just one of that two columns.

This is my query:

```
(SELECT tblfacturas.id                 AS ID, 
        tblclientes.razonsocial        AS Cliente, 
        tblfacturas.fecha              AS Fecha, 
        tblfacturas.tipocomprobante    AS Tipo, 
        tblfacturas.nrofacturacompleto AS Numero, 
        tblfacturas.total              AS Debe 
 FROM   tblfacturas 
        left join tblclientes 
               ON tblclientes.id = tblfacturas.id_cliente 
 WHERE  tblclientes.razonsocial = 'S.A.') 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT tblrecibos.id                AS ID, 
        tblclientes.razonsocial      AS Cliente, 
        tblrecibos.fecha             AS Fecha, 
        'R'                          AS Tipo, 
        tblrecibos.nrorecibocompleto AS Numero, 
        tblrecibos.total             AS Haber 
 FROM   tblrecibos 
        left join tblclientes 
               ON tblclientes.id = tblrecibos.id_cliente 
 WHERE  tblclientes.razonsocial = 'S.A.') 
ORDER  BY fecha
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 0):

you need  null for add  a column Debe and Haber where not present otherwise you obtain  both the result in the same columns  (Debe)

```
  SELECT TblFacturas.id as ID
  , TblClientes.razonsocial as Cliente
  ,TblFacturas.fecha as Fecha
  ,TblFacturas.tipocomprobante as Tipo
  ,TblFacturas.nrofacturacompleto as Numero
  , TblFacturas.total as Debe 
  , null as Haber 
  FROM TblFacturas 
  left join TblClientes on TblClientes.id = TblFacturas.id_cliente 
  where TblClientes.razonsocial = 'S.A.' 
UNION ALL

  SELECT TblRecibos.id 
  , TblClientes.razonsocial 
  ,TblRecibos.fecha 
  , 'R' 
  ,TblRecibos.nrorecibocompleto 
  , null 
  , TblRecibos.total 
  FROM TblRecibos 
  left join TblClientes on TblClientes.id = TblRecibos.id_cliente 
  where TblClientes.razonsocial = 'S.A.'
  order by fecha
```

And another suggestion .. you have column involved  in left join in where clause this work as an inner join   excluding rows  if the left joined  values is not present  for this  you should
or  move the where condition in the on clause  (if you need  also the not macthing rows )

```
  SELECT TblRecibos.id 
  , TblClientes.razonsocial 
  ,TblRecibos.fecha 
  , 'R' 
  ,TblRecibos.nrorecibocompleto 
  , null 
  , TblRecibos.total 
  FROM TblRecibos 
  left join TblClientes on TblClientes.id = TblRecibos.id_cliente 
    AND  TblClientes.razonsocial = 'S.A.'
```

or use inner join  if you need only matching rows

```
  SELECT TblRecibos.id 
  , TblClientes.razonsocial 
  ,TblRecibos.fecha 
  , 'R' 
  ,TblRecibos.nrorecibocompleto 
  , null 
  , TblRecibos.total 
  FROM TblRecibos 
  INNER join TblClientes on TblClientes.id = TblRecibos.id_cliente 
    AND  TblClientes.razonsocial = 'S.A.'
```

Comment: You undo my edit :(. but nvm. Regarding your other suggestion I belive the `LEFT JOIN` is the way to go.The problem is the table order is reversed. A Client may or may not have Facturas (bills) same with Recibos (receipts) and you can filter only customer with `'S.A.'` in the  `WHERE`

Comment: Dont worry I know that happen. I dont think Inner Join will work, because you can have Client without receipts or bills.